# Call phpunit from console in my symfony project

Tags: php, bash, symfony, console, phpunit

this is my current status:
I have a running symfony environment, based on a docker image. Everything works fine and from PHPStorm i can execute phpunit tests. But i want to execute them manually from console.

After i started all services by using `docker-compose up --build`, i login into the phpfpm service by: `docker-compose exec -it phpfpm bash`

then i move into my symfony project folder that contain all folders and files like "app/, bin/, vendor/, ... composer.json... etc"

I could go by calling `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` but i want to get a shorter way. Is there any chance, maybe calling `bin/phpunit` or something like this?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPUnit has that script in the [own composer.json](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/composer.json#L64), so `bin` (or `vendor/bin`) directory should contains a relevant symlink after running `composer install`. Also check your composer.json for [`bin-dir`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md) settings.

At least you always can create a symlink:

```
$ ln -s vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit phpunit
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html) the preferable way of using phpunit is by `.phar` file. In this way you can download phpunit as a `.phar` file and it will works both outside and inside docker container.

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.0.phar
php phpunit-6.0.phar --version
```

Type now `php phpunit-6.0.phar` to run tests.